# $16$ kids dividing candies between their neighbors, prove that eventually a cycle will occur.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

16 kids are playing a game. They sit on a 4 by 4 grid. Each kid has initial number of candies. Every turn, if a kid have more candies than the number of their neighbors (depending on the position of the kid, he will obviously have 2-4 neighbors), he will give each neighbor one candy. If the kid has fewer candies than the number of their neighbors, he will not give out any candies, but will continue to receive candies from his neighbors.

If we call how many candies each kid has a "state" of the game, prove that no matter what the initial state is, the states of the game will eventually recycle. For example if there is only one candy among 16 kids, in the next state this candy stays with the same kid, and the state of the game "recycles".

I wrote a python program to validate the claim. It seems indeed legit. I have tried to formulate this problem into either an Eulerian path, or a matrix multiplication, but so far has failed..

Comment: By "recycle" do you mean that it's a steady state (period 1), or a sequence of states that eventually repeats (period n)?

Comment: @CalvinLin eventually repeat (period n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the total number of candies on the board doesn't change after each step! Let $N$ be the initial number of candies.

Let $X$ be the set of states in which each square has $\leq N$ candies. There are $(N+1)^{16}$ such states, so $\lvert X \rvert = (N+1)^{16}$.

Now let the sequence of states be $I_0, I_1, \ldots$ so that each state $I_n$ is an element of $X$. Then consider the first $(N+1)^{16}+1$ states,

$$I_0, I_1, \dots, I_{(N+1)^{16}}$$

This is a list of $(N+1)^{16} + 1$ elements of $X$, but $X$ has only $(N+1)^{16}$ elements, so by the pigeonhole principle, at least two of these states are the same! In other words, $I_i = I_j$ for some $i < j \leq (N+1)^{16}$, and the game repeats with period dividing $j-i$.